# Nested directories in SQL using java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, tree

I have to create a nested system of directories in a database and make the users able to download files from them. 
I don't know how to set up the tree structure in SQL and use the proper commmands in java to make queries and let the user view or download the file.
Does anyone know how to help me or do you have a proper link with all the questions below?
I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres supports tree as a column datatype. Here is the documentation
: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ltree.html

And also you can create a table with recursive relationship (reference to itself) to replicate a tree structure
Here is the table for example :

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  parent int,
  level int
)
```

Column parent is foreign key to column id and column level is to know the depth of the node (if you visualize it as tree).